# iOS 8 viewDidAppear called before appWillBecomeActive?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, viewdidappear

I'm just experiencing something weird and it seems to be a change in iOS 8.
Previously(iOS7) when testing `appWillBecomeActive` was called before `viewDidAppear`. Is it so that in iOS 8 it is the other way around? what would then be a good workaround in order to make my app work on both iOS versions? is there some variable to test if `viewDidAppear` was called so I could run my setup functions of the view again?

EDIT: it actually seems quite random in iOS8. sometimes `viewDidAppear` is called before `appWillBecomeActive`. Sometimes it's the other way around...

Comment: `appDidLaunch...` will called before `viewDidAppear:`, why not move the logic from appWillBecomeActive there ?

Comment: I cannot find any documentation of appDidLaunch....

Comment: Sorry, it is `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: Do you mean `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` or `-[<UIApplicationDelegate> applicationDidBecomeActive:]`? There is no `will` equivalent AFAIK. If so, please edit your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

appWillBecomeActive is a delegate located in your Application Delegate itself.. there's no guarantee that it will be called before any other UIViewController delegates (viewWillAppear,DidLoad,Init)

if you want to make any logic before loading of any other pages come alive.. you may want to use `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and you may want to load the launching view by yourself or create a new delegate to detect that you finished the logic that you'll put in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` .

Comment: that makes some sense but I've implemented application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in my delegate already. so I cannot have it in my main file any more, right? what do I do?

Comment: ok. was a rather stupid question. just moved it to a custom function and called it from the delegate. seems to work reliably for first 3 tests...